# How do I start a new game?

Tags: android, virtual-city-playground

How do I start a new game within Virtual City Playground? When I load the app, I just have an option to start playing. I don't see anything throughout the game menu to restart or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an option in the game, but you could always wipe the app's data in the "Manage Applications" section of the settings.

[Wipe data and cache for an application in Android](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/wipe-data-cache-android-31671.html)

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, especially with how much I'm using the tablet to play games and stuff lol. Worked like a charm though, thanks!!